# Cloning Laravel GitHub Repository

Tags: laravel, git, web, web-development-server

I’m new in working with Laravel and I want to clone a GitHub Laravel project to see how it works. I executed the commands: git clone, composer install and php artisan serve. I do get the laravel development server URL, but when I tried to run the project on the browser I get a server error 500. I feel that I’m missing some commands, If so, could you tell me which ones?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you able to share the GitHub repo with the laravel project as that might help.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping, I already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing some commands. I had the same trouble a couple of moths ago, let me share with you some of my class notes on the steps you need to follow.

1. Open the terminal.
2. With the use of the command cd go te directory where you want save the project.

   Example: cd Desktop
3. Execute de command: git clone [GitHub Repository URL]

   Example: git clone https://github.com/User/RepositoryName.git
4. With the use of the command cd go te project directory.

   Example: cd Desktop
   Example: cd RepositoryName

   Note: You will probably just have to execute de last one, because you
   will be already in the Desktop directory if you executed the
   commands in order.
5. Use the command: git status to know if your repository is updated.

   Example: git status
6. Use the command: git fetch && git pull to update your local repository with the external repository.

   Example: git fetch && git pull
7. Make sure you are in the outer developing branch (it is regularly named develop) of your project by executing the command git branch -a, it will display the branches and show you the current branch.

   Example: git branch -a
8. Use the command git checkout branchName to move to the outer developing branch (it is regularly named develop).

   Example: git checkout develop
9. In case of having your project divided in projectName and projectNameAPI you will have to execute the following commands in both directories.

   Example: cd projectName
   Example: Execute the step 10 commands

   Then used de cd .. command to return to de RepositoryName directory and then execute the cd     projectNameAPI and execute the step 10 commands.

   Example: cd ..
   Example: cd projectNameAPI
   Example: Execute the step 10 commands
10. Execute the following commands.

    npm I
    npm run dev
    composer install
    cp .env.example .env
    php artisan key:generate

In case of using a database, in this case XAMPP

11. Open XAMPP and start the MySQL Database Server and the Apache Web Server
12. Open XAMPP on your browser and on the URL write http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

    Example: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
13. Create a data base
14. Go to privileges
15. Add a new user account
16. Enter a userName, select Local host and live the name that it has and click on generate password. Click on continue and live all the other fields as they appear.
17. Open the env. file of you project and Enter the database name, the user and the password.

    Example:
    DB_DATABASE=databaseNamee
    DB_USERNAME=userName
    DB_PASSWORD=password
18. Go to the terminal and go to the projectName directory or in case that you are using api go to the projectNameAPI directory and run the command php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

    Note: If you are using an API just run the command in the API
    directory.

    Example: cd Desktop
    Example: cd Project
    Example: cd RepositoryName
    Example: cd projectName
    Example: php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
19. Positioned in your projectName directory run the project with the command php artisan serve

    Example: cd Desktop
    Example: cd Project
    Example: cd RepositoryName
    Example: cd projectName
    Example: php artisan serve
20. The previous    command will generate a URL, copy it and paste it on the URL of your browser and your project will start running.

Note: You can use the command ls to know what is inside the directory you
are in.
Note: You can use the command cd .. to move to a directory outter from
where you are.